# Angular 5 HttpParams no detecto parametros

Tags: angular5

Con el siguiente código al enviar un POST con HTTPClient de Angular 5

```
     let params = new HttpParams({     // ==== NO FUNCIONA BIEN  ¿? !!
      fromObject: {
        topic_id: topic_id.toString(),
        answer_id: answer_id.toString(),
        question_id: question_id.toString(),
        ...this.commonParams()
      }
    });

    let params2 = {                      // ==== así SI funciona
      topic_id: topic_id.toString(),
      answer_id: answer_id.toString(),
      question_id: question_id.toString(),
      ...this.commonParams()
    };

    console.log(' ............', params2);
    return this.http.post(this.url + '/respuesta', params2);
```

Si utilizo "param" no veo los datos (o no se como leerlos en el servidor REST) y si utilizo "param2" (un objeto directamente) no hay problema...

No consigo entender porqué

gracias

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo de la siguiente manera:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

let params = new HttpParams();

let object = { topic_id: topic_id.toString(),
               answer_id: answer_id.toString(),
               question_id: question_id.toString()};

params = params.set('fromObject', object);

return this.http.put(this.url+'/respuesta', params, { headers: headers })
```

Answer (score -1):

Si la segunda forma te funciona, deberías usarla (es más sencilla, además), pero creo que el problema está en que has añadido tus parámetros anidados:

```
let params = new HttpParams({     // ==== NO FUNCIONA BIEN  ¿? !!
  fromObject: { // <-- Esto sobra
    topic_id: topic_id.toString(),
    answer_id: answer_id.toString(),
    question_id: question_id.toString(),
    ...this.commonParams()
  }
});
```

Prueba con

```
let params = new HttpParams({
    topic_id: topic_id.toString(),
    answer_id: answer_id.toString(),
    question_id: question_id.toString(),
    ...this.commonParams()
});
```